# JQuery Loading Dynamic Content off Dynamic Content

Tags: php, jquery, html

I was wondering if someone would be able to help or point me in a direction. I am looking to make a web application like a quiz. What I need is to be able to load dynamic content off a dynamical created button or href in this case that will link to the other content. So far it doesnt seem to be functioning in that i get a page not found every time i click the button. doesnt seem to be passing the .php through the name. I have tested this outside of the dynmaic content div and it works fine but i really need it to work inside.
What I have so far:

**index.php**

```
<body>
<div class="container_12">

    <div id="content">
    <!--dynamic content loads here-->
    </div>
</div>  

</body>
```

**Login.php**

```
<h1> Login Page </h1>
    <p> this is a test to c if works </p> 
        <a href='Suitable'>Hello</a> <!--button that doesnt work-->
```

**general.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//initial
    $('#content').load('Login.php');

    //Handle widget Clicks 
    $('div#content a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('pages/' + page +'.php');
        return false;

    });
});
```

**Suitable.php**

```
<h1> Working </h1>
<!-- content thats not loading off button-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should delegate the `click` event for dynamically loaded elements, try the following:

```
$('#content').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load('pages/' + page +'.php');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //initial
    $('#content').load('Login.php', function(){
        //Handle widget Clicks 
        $('div#content a').click(function() {
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#content').load('pages/' + page +'.php');
            return false;

        });

    });

});
```

Explanation:

`load` is asynchronous. JS engine does not wait for it to complete before it goes to the next line. The result is that when your `click` binding executes there is no `a` in `div#content`, so the selector returns an empty array and no binding happens.

Answer (score -1):

Try `Live` instead of `click`

//Handle widget Clicks

```
$('div#content a').live('click',function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load('pages/' + page +'.php');
    return false;

});
```